# replacing text with cleaned word case insensitive c#

Tags: c#, replace, case-insensitive

I have a list of bad words, that if found in the text string, will be replaced by a cleaned word.
eg. `badwords{woof} is replaced by w$$f`

But is currently only working when the array list is in the same case as the matched word in the sentence.

`var badWords = new List<string>{"woof", "meow"}`

`var string = "I have a cat named meow and a dog name Woof."`
Should become === "I have a cat named m$$w and a dog name W$$f"

```
public string CensorText(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return text;
        }
        foreach (string word in CensoredWords)
        {
            text = text.Replace(word, WordCleaner(word));
        }
        return text;
    }

    private static string WordCleaner(string wordToClean)
    {
        string firstChar = wordToClean.Substring(0,1);
        string lastChar = wordToClean.Substring(wordToClean.Length - 1);
        string centerHash = new string('$', wordToClean.Length-2);

        return string.Concat(firstChar, centerHash, lastChar);         
    }
```

How can make it so that its case insensitive when looping through the words and cleaning them. Simpler the answer is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
text = text.Replace(word, WordCleaner(word));
```

with

```
text = text.Replace(word.ToLower(), WordCleaner(word));
```

This converts any upper case letter to a lower case one.

### Edit

I've realised that I've made the wrong variable into lower case.

Change:

```
public string CensorText(string text)
{
```

To:

```
public string CensorText(string text)
{
    text = text.ToLower();
```

### Edit 2

To retain the original sentence with the censored words changed, it would be much easier to use `re` instead. First, revert your file back to how it was in the question.

Now replace:

```
text = text.Replace(word, WordCleaner(word));
```

with:

```
text = regex.replace(text,word,WordCleaner(word),RegexOptions.Ignorecase);
```

Comment: I've just tried that, and unfortunately, it just ignores the word in the string.

Comment: that edit did the trick, but has now changed the entire sentence to output in lowercase @0liveradam8

Comment: import re is python code, re.compile is not available within C#

Comment: but now the wordcleaner is outputting one or two incorrect $ for each word in List<string>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple option you can use.
The benefit is you don't care which of the word is lower case, it'll work for either cases. Note that compare returns an int, hence why we check it's 0 for a match.

```
string input = "the Woof is on Fire, we don't need no bucket, leT the ...";
string[] bad_words = new string[] {"woof","fire","BucKet", "Let"};

foreach (var word in input.Split(' ')) {
    if (bad_words.Any( b => String.Compare( word, b // Following line does what you want:
                                          , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
        Console.Write(WordCleaner(word));
    else
        Console.Write(word);
}
```

Output:

```
the W$$f is on F$$e  we don't need no b$$$$t  l$T the ...
```

Seems fine to me. Note that if you split on space, a word with a comma right after will have that  comma as part of the word

Comment: when i substitued the Console.Writeline with WordCleaner, the capital letter is still not getting acknowledged. Larger is not equal to larger

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, works as per above with your method